# How to check if an R object has a certain attribute?

Tags: r

How can I check if an R object has a certain attribute?
For example, I would like to check if a vector has a "labels" attribute. How can I do this? Exists already a function that does that?

```
my_vector <- c(1, 2, 3)
my_vector_labelled <- `attr<-`(my_vector, "labels", c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3))
```

let's assume there is a function named `has_attribute(x, attr)`. The the expected result would be:

```
> has_attribute(my_vector, "labels")
 FALSE
> has_attribute(my_vector_labelled, "labels")
 TRUE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways:

- `%in% names(attributes(..)`:

  ```r
  "labels" %in% names(attributes(my_vector))
  # [1] FALSE
  "labels" %in% names(attributes(my_vector_labelled))
  # [1] TRUE
  ```
- `is.null(attr(..,""))`:

  ```r
  is.null(attr(my_vector, "labels"))
  # [1] TRUE                                   # NOT present
  is.null(attr(my_vector_labelled, "labels"))
  # [1] FALSE                                  # present
  ```

  (Perhaps `!is.null(attr(..))` is preferred?)

Answer (score 2):

There is a function available in package

```
> library(BBmisc)
> hasAttributes(my_vector_labelled, "labels")
[1] TRUE
> hasAttributes(my_vector, "labels")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `attributes`.

```r
my_vector <- c(1, 2, 3)
my_vector_labelled <- `attr<-`(my_vector, "labels", c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)) 

attributes(my_vector)
#> NULL
names(attributes(my_vector_labelled))
#> [1] "labels"

has_attribute <- function(x, which){
  which %in% names(attributes(x))
}
has_attribute(my_vector_labelled, "labels")
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Did you mean to use `names(attributes(x))`?